Google signin show popup app want to use google.com to Sign In 2 times

I have some trouble with Google Auth in React Native (v0.74) with google sign in
I using this method base on firebase docs
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
In the first time when I click Signin with Google, it open request access pop up, then show popup of google to select and contine signin. When I click in continue it open the request access pop up again and I have to click continue again then it work




Here is my code

Here is where I'm implement it 

I've tried to find if it return data in the first time open or not, but it not.

In first time when click continue it have idToken and googleCredentials data. It close pop up and then open the modal request access to login with Google again



Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code
